# Covariant derivative in spherical coordinates

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, differentiation, vector-fields

Let's say I have a 4-vector $A^{\nu}$ and I take its covariant derivative (I'm using cartesian coordinates), so:

$\nabla_{\mu} A^{\nu}=\partial_{\mu}A^{\nu}+\Gamma^{\nu}_{\mu \alpha} A^{\alpha}$

But if I now go to spherical coordinates and I look at the radial covariant derivative, I have:

$\nabla_{r} A^{\nu}=\frac{1}{r^{2}}\partial_{r}(r^{2}A^{\nu})+\Gamma^{\nu}_{r \alpha} A^{\alpha}$

My question is where do the additional $r^{2}$ factors come from? Why isn't it just:

$\nabla_{r} A^{\nu}=\partial_{r}(A^{\nu})+\Gamma^{\nu}_{r \alpha} A^{\alpha}$ ?

Comment: Isn't it a [transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_transformation) that is happening, rather than an index label change?

Comment: @KyleKanos is correct. Think of how the divergence from usual calculus is transformed from cartesian to polar coordinates. You could perform this calculation for yourself by transforming the vector using the metric which would gives a factor of $r^2$ and $r^-2$ when transforming the partial derivative.